# Adding attributes to “list.phtml” for compare page

Tags: product, compare

I want to show all attributes of a product in compare page. I added this code in `catalog/product/compare/list.phtml` but I get this error:

```
<h2><?php echo (
        (
            $_item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('admin_rating')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item->getProduct() )
            && $_item->getProduct() ->getResource()->getAttribute('admin_rating')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item->getProduct() ) != "Nein"
        )
        ? $_item->getProduct() ->getResource()->getAttribute('admin_rating')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item->getProduct() )
        : ''
    ); ?></h2>
```

> ERROR: Fatal error: Call to a member function getResource() on a non-object in ...\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\compare\list.phtml on line 78

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the result for $_item->getProduct() is not an object, thus you can't call any methods. Make sure when you call $_item that has a product.

If you want to show all the attributes of the product you can instead try to get the product id and load it like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('PRODUCT_ID_HERE');
$product->getData(); //this will return all the attributes
```

You will need to load the product again just to make sure you are loading all the attributes, but also you can work with the already loaded product if it already has all the attributes you need.

Comment: I added your code but no attributes shows in compare page.